# How Do I Use Logarithms to calculate the sum of a Geometric Series

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, geometric-series

I've run into a problem while trying to program something and I'm not much of a mathematician, so I'm hoping someone can jog my memory on how to handle this.

I'd like to know how much time it would take for each amount at each discrete time interval to summate to a specific value if those additive sums decrease exponentially over time. Knowing the initial amount ($a = 0.125$), the decay rate($1 - r = 0.98$), and the final sum ($\sum i = 5$), **I need to solve for time ($t$)**.

I'd imagine the equation would look something like:

$\sum i = a(1-r)^t$

$5 = 0.125(0.98)^t$

Though it's been nearly two decades since I've had to use this notation, so I may be off. I understand how to solve for time if I'm just trying to solve for a lower value at some later point (i.e., $t$ = $\ln(f(x)/a)/\ln(1-r))$. However, if I am to more or less sum the product of each iteration of $a(1-r)^t$ until it reaches value $\sum i$, I'm lost. Someone else had instructed me that I just need to use logarithms, but after looking for a few hours, I'm frankly confused as to how to apply a logarithm to the equation above to solve for time. Any help is truly appreciated it.

Comment: Did you mean final *amount* = 30, or final *sum* (as in the sum of each amount at a discrete time interval) = 30? Those are very different things. Example, if I start with an initial amount of $16$ at initial $t=0$ and every second I decay to half the original amount, I'll go $16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25...$. The final *amount* at time $t = 3$ is $2$ but the *sum* is $30$. Be precise. Also, you're starting with a low amount of $0.125$ and growing to $30$? That's not decay, so expect your time to come back negative.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; sorry for the confusion. The value $a$ at $t+1$ should be $98%$ of $a$'s value at timepoint $t$, and so that's what I intended to communicate with decay, just to clarify. Also to clarify the first point, I am aiming to calculate the sum, rather than the amount, as you had described it. Thirty was also a mistake given the inital amount. I'll correct those points real quick. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: See my answer (based on your old question). You can substitute $10$ for $30$ and get the new value. But it doesn't change the fact that your $t$ will still be negative.

Comment: @Deepak Ah, sorry! You must have seen my response too late. I appreciate you taking the time to write this out, though. I do understand calculating the *final amount* (I had noted the same approach you had taken in the original comment e.g., $t=ln(f(x)/a)/ln(1−r))$). I'm really stuck on this issue of *final sum*. Perhaps it's clearer to specify: If I were to essentially calculate a series of values, each being 98% of the value preceding it (i.e., 0.1250, 0.1225,0.1201, 0.1176, etc.), how long before the sum of those values equals 10?

Comment: I'm a bit busy, I'll try to help later (unless someone beats me to it), but you should read about geometric sequences (the progression of amounts) and series (the cumulative sums of amounts). The wiki is helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20geometric%20progression,number%20called%20the%20common%20ratio. It is possible to solve your new question with logs as well.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the help

Comment: Please take a look at my completely revised answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take you through a complete solution, especially now that you've clarified you're interested in the *sum* as well. I an going to be focussing on your edited final "target" sum of $5$.

A geometric sequence (or progression) is one that goes like this:

$a, ar, ar^2, ar^3, ..., ar^{n-1}, ...$

You start with the initial term $a$, and to go from one term to the next, you multiply by the common ratio $r$. The $n$-th term is $ar^{n-1}$, which makes sense since you're starting with a first term of $a = ar^0$.

However, your conventions are slightly different. You're starting at an initial time $t=0$, and your common ratio seems to be denoted $(1-r)$ (instead of $r$), so your sequence is going:

$a, a(1-r), a(1-r)^2, ..., a(1-r)^t, ...$

and the *amount* at time $t$ is $a(1-r)^t$.

Now I'll show you how to derive an expression for the *sum* of this series (up to time $t$).

The sum to time $t$ is given by $S_t = a + a(1-r) + a(1-r)^2 + ... + a(1-r)^t$

If you did something really interesting, i.e. multiply by $(1-r)$, this is what you get:

$(1-r)S_t = a(1-r) + a(1-r)^2 + a(1-r)^3 + ... + a(1-r)^t + a(1-r)^{t+1}$

Now try subtracting the new expression from the original:

$S_t - (1-r)S_t =  a + a(1-r) + a(1-r)^2 + ... + a(1-r)^t - (a(1-r) + a(1-r)^2 + a(1-r)^3 + ... + a(1-r)^t + a(1-r)^{t+1})$

$rS_t = a - a(1-r)^{t+1}$

$S_t = \frac{a(1 - (1-r)^{t+1})}{r}$

And there's your formula.

(You will note that the formula looks somewhat different from "standard" formulae for geometric sums. This is because the way you defined the parameters in your question is different. For the record, the standard formula for the geometric sum is $S_n = \frac{a(1 - r^n)}{1 - r}$, but the parameters mean something different in that formula, so don't confuse yourself).

Anyway, working with this formula that I've derived, you have $1-r = 0.98 \implies r = 0.02$. You have $a = 0.125$. You want to find the value of $t$ at which the *sum* $S_t$ reaches $5$ (the value you put in after your edit).

We have:

$5 = \frac{0.125(1 - (0.98)^{t+1})}{0.02}$

Rearranging, $\frac{(5)(0.02)}{0.125} = 1 - (0.98)^{t+1})$

$\frac 45 = 1 - (0.98)^{t+1}$

$(0.98)^{t+1} = \frac 15$

Taking logarithms of both sides by before and exploiting the same property of logs (bringing the index down, we get:

$(t+1)\log 0.98 = \log 0.2$

$t \approx 79.66$

So it would take at least $80$ units of time for the sum to *just exceed* your target of $5$.

Interestingly, if you put in "target" sums of $10$ or $30$ like you had before your final edit, you will not be able to get a sensible (real) value for $t$. This is because the *infinite series* (sum to an infinite number of terms) of a progression starting out at $0.125$ and being iteratively multiplied by $0.98$ each time will still only sum to $6.25$, so that's the maximum bound for a sum for any finite number of terms. So it's good that you amended the question to an answerable one with your edit.

Answer (score 0):

@Deepak's direction was a huge help and I read more on Geometric series, which lead me to this handy tool, which will not only calculate the final sum, but demonstrate how it arrived at that calculation as well.
https://www.mathportal.org/calculators/sequences-calculators/geometric-sequences-calculator.php

[Calculation work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SlzV.png)

Edit: the above link demonstrates the work, but because of Stack Exchange's very conservative reputation system I can't actually insert the image in-text; just a link. I found it at 2am on my phone, so if I can, I'll come back later and type it out proper, but for now this will do.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have completely revised my answer, please take a look.